# Smarty 2.6.14 and PHP 5.4.9 doesn't recognize {literal} tag

Tags: php, smarty, smarty2

I've a html page with php smarty tags. 
The problem is the `{literal}` tags, needed to escape javascript and css code block. 
In many others php versions, like php 5.3 or 5.5 works fine,  but in php 5.4.9 doesn't work

When i use `{literal}` to escape javascript, like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
    $(function () {

        jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
        test = document.createElement('input');
        if('placeholder' in test) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;

        if (!$.support.placeholder) {
            $('.field').find ('label').show ();
        }

    });
{/literal}
</script>
```

I get a `"Fatal error: Smarty error: [in login.html line 70]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: php' . str_repeat(" ", substr_count('{literal (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 446) in /var/www/library/smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1095"` and the line 70 is the code `{literal}`.

But if i remove `{literal}`tags and use `{ldelim}` and `{rdelim}` this works fine, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {ldelim}

        jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
        test = document.createElement('input');
        if('placeholder' in test) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;

        if (!$.support.placeholder) {ldelim}
            $('.field').find ('label').show ();
        {rdelim}

    {rdelim});
</script>
```

I do not consider as a solution change all tags `{literal}` in the project for `{ldelim}` and `{rdelim}`, when i have the same project working fine in others php versions and when i have lot of pages escaping javascript's and css with `{literal}`.

Comment: From the error, it looks like that version of Smarty is just fundamentally broken. Sadly, you might be SOL :/

Comment: That, or attempt to fix it yourself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's a bug in this Smarty version when running this PHP version. I would advise you to use the newest 3.x Smarty and if you cannot, you should test the last Smarty 2.6.28 to check if this bug was removed and then decide whether to move to this Smarty vesion.

Comment: It also seems someone already had the same problem - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35519&edit=1 but on other PHP version

Comment: it worked fine after upgraded smarty to 2.6.28! thanks.